# Convert input files to byte[] javascript

Tags: javascript, file, input, base64

I'm working on a REST web application that manages documents between users and uploaders. The backend is written in Java and my Document entity contains, besides various attributes, a `byte[] content`. I was able to send a file created at server side by

```
@GET
...
document.setContent(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("WEB-INF/testFile.txt")));
return Response.ok(document).build();
```

and retrieve it at front-end (vueJs) through

```
async function download(file) {
  const fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([atob(file.content)]));
  const fileLink = document.createElement("a");

  fileLink.href = fileURL;
  fileLink.setAttribute("download",`${file.name}.${file.type}`);
  document.body.appendChild(fileLink);
  fileLink.click();
  fileLink.remove;
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileURL);
}
```

the **problem** is that when I try to upload a file and then download it, its content is not parsed correctly (is shown undefined, string in Base64 or numbers depending on how I try to solve it). The file is sent by a post request and is retrieved through an input form bound to an `onFileSelected` function.

```
function onFileSelected(e) {

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.target.files[0]);
  reader.onloadend = (evt) => {
    if (evt.target.readyState === FileReader.DONE) {
      var arrayBuffer = evt.target.result;
      this.file.content = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
      //this.file.content = arrayBuffer;
    }
  };
  
}

axios.post(...,document,...)
```

and I have tried using `atob` and `btoa` as well before assigning the value to `this.file.content`. If I print the file on server Welcome.txt it gives `B@ae3b74d` and if I use `Arrays.toString(welcome.getContent())` it gives an array of numbers but as soon as it passed to the frontend its content become in Base64 `welcome: { ... content: IFRoaXMgaXMgYSB0ZXN0IGZpbGUhIAo...}`. Any idea? Thank you a lot!

Comment: `atob('IFRoaXMgaXMgYSB0ZXN0IGZpbGUhIAo') === ' This is a test file! \n'`

Comment: I do see a properly formatted `Base64` string. The content is different than the one specified by you: `B@ae3b74d`. Please clarify your objectives. What you are attempting to do, how are you currently doing it (broadly without posting all your code) and where exactly do you face the issue.